# Не могу придумать как сделать объединение

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> 8. (*A* ∪ *B*) \ *C*

Правильно ли я сделал?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <locale.h> 
#include <time.h> 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int *A, *B, *C, *mas1, *mas2;
    int na, nb, nc, max;

    printf("Кол-во элементов во множестве А : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &na);
    system("cls");

    printf("Кол-во элементов во множестве B : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &nb);
    system("cls");

    printf("Кол-во элементов во множестве C : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &nc);
    system("cls");

    if (na > nb && na > nc)
    {
        max = na;
    }
    else if (nb > na && nb > nc)
    {
        max = nb;
    }
    else
    {
        max = nc;
    }

    A = (int*)malloc(na * sizeof(int));
    B = (int*)malloc(nb * sizeof(int));
    C = (int*)malloc(nc * sizeof(int));
    mas1 = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));
    mas2 = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));
    memset(mas1, 0, sizeof(max));
    memset(mas2, 0, sizeof(max));

    for (int i = 0; i < na; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        B[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
    {
        C[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        int j = 0, k = 0;
        while (A[j] != B[i] && j < na) j++;
        while (mas1[k] != B[i] && k < max) k++;
        if (j != na && k == max)
        {
            mas1[max++] = B[i];
        }
    }
    printf("1 мн-во:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < na; i++)
        printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);

    printf("2 мн-во:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
        printf("B[%d] = %d\n", i, B[i]);

    printf("Результат выполнения операции \"Пересечение\":");
    printf("AB = {");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        printf(" %d", mas1[i]);
    printf("};\n");

    int max1 = 0;
    //Сюда нужно объединение 
    printf("1 мн-во:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        printf("AB[%d] = %d\n", i, mas1[i]);

    printf("2 мн-во:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++)
        printf("C[%d] = %d\n", i, C[i]);

    printf("Результат выполнения операции \"Разность\":\n");
    printf("AB - С = {");
    for (int i = 0; i < max1; i++)
        printf(" %d", mas2[i]);
    printf("};\n");



    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Объединение множеств в теории множеств — множество, содержащее в себе
>   все элементы исходных множеств.

Следовательно, множество `AB = A + B` содержит в себе элемены множества `A` и `B`, исключая повторяющиеся.
Для начала я бы посоветовал вместо обычных динамических массивов использовать контейнеры стандартной библиотеки.
Тогда самым простым решением будет создать функцию `std::vector<int> unionOfSets(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
)`, где `a` и `b` являются объединяемыми множествами, которая будет возвращать множество `a + b`.
Например

```
std::vector<int> unionOfSets(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b)
{
    std::vector<int> result(a); // result = a

    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
    {
        bool contain = false; // Содержится ли элемент в результирующем множестве
        for(int j = 0; j < result.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(result[j] == b[i])
            {
                contain = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!contain) result.push_back(b[i]); // Если не содержится, то добавляем его к результирующему множесту
    }
    return result;
}
```

P.S. Данное решение подходит только если вам необходимо самому написать самое простое и примитивное решение, для остального исчерпывающий ответ дал оратор ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж тэг С++ - не хотите попробовать стандартные алгоритмы?

```
set<int> A, B;
....
set<int> Res;
set_union(A.begin(),A.end(),B.begin(),B.end(),
          inserter(D,D.begin()));
```

Ну, а для разности множеств - `set_difference`.

Comment: Ну лучше будет для Си, просто еще не сильно в этом разбираюсь